# Run script after node server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

We have an application that has the following three scripts inside package.json...

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start-electron\" \"npm run start-webpack\" -n \"electron,webpack\" -p name",
"start-electron": "electron -r babel-register ./js-file",
"start-webpack": "node -r babel-register scripts/js-file-2.js"
```

When we run `npm start`, both `start-electron` and `start-webpack` scripts are called. We are using Concurrently to run both scripts at the same time.

There is a major issue. When we start the Webpack script, it makes a HTTP request to the Node server. Because these two scripts are running concurrently, we can't guarantee the Node server will be running when we run the Webpack script.

Here's my question. How can I run the Webpack script as soon as the Node server starts and avoid this race condition?

Comment: Do they really need to run next to each other? Any chance that you could create a node program that launches `electron`, and either checks if it's running or waits a certain amount of time before running the webpack command?

Comment: You could create another script that wraps your webpack task and checks if you can access a given port

Comment: @Icepickle I've thought about that. They don't need to run next to each other. What I'm hoping is to get information on how I can check to see if the node is running before running webpack. I think a bash command would be best. for this but I'm not entirely sure. I also like lumio's idea.

Comment: Create a command that reads an argument that has the server target address, start electron and create head request to the given url, once it's running, launch webpack. I guess both commands stay alive (webpack is probably watching files, electron manages the server). Any chance electron could be started through webpack? A bit like [this](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack)

Comment: @Icepicke, post as an answer and I'll give your credit. This gives me a great head-start into fixing this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they really need to run next to each other? Any chance that you could create a node program that launches `electron`, and either checks if it's running or waits a certain amount of time before running the `webpack` command?

As an idea you could implement something like this:

- Create a nodejs program that reads an argument that has the server target address,
- start electron and create head request to the given url,
- once it's running, launch webpack.

I guess both commands stay alive (webpack is probably watching files, electron manages the server).

You could check into integrations between electron and webpack, for example, [this one](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack)